# Carrierwave can't save the image, using an engine

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I'm learning to use Carrierwave the first step is obviously to upload a picture and see if it's effectively inserted to the database. One detail that could be important is that this code is written in a Rails Engine and namespaced (`Wanker`)

I generated an uploader following the instruction of the gem, everything went good (`Wanker::PicturesUploader`)

I made a model `CompanyDetailImage` with a `picture` string field (MySQL) and added this line

```
mount_uploader :picture, Wanker::PicturesUploader
```

Then I made a view and a form

```
<%= f.fields_for [:wanker, @company, @company_detail, @company_detail_images] %>

    <%= i.label :picture %>
    <%= i.file_field :picture %>

<% end %>
```

The `params[:company][:company_detail_image]["picture"]` in the controller will have this inside of it

```
[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fe613b81f40
   @content_type="image/png",
   @headers=
   "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"company[company_detail_image][picture][]\"; filename=\"Screen Shot 2015-02-04 at 8.18.58 PM.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n",
  @original_filename="Screen Shot 2015-02-04 at 8.18.58 PM.png",
  @tempfile=#    <File:/var/folders/2w/lw3glw5d58g25qvv4cx6yk0m0000gn/T/RackMultipart20150213-22947-np2et6>>]
```

Which for me seemed good. But when I try this

```
@company_detail_image = Wanker::CompanyDetailImage.new
@company_detail_image.picture = params[:company][:company_detail_image]["picture"]
@company_detail_image.save!
```

It returns this

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Picture You are not allowed to upload nil files, allowed types: jpg, jpeg, gif, png
```

Does someone has an idea why it doesn't catch the picture ? Thank you guys ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@company_detail_image.picture = params[:company][:company_detail_image]["picture"].first
```

This is because your `["picture"]` param is returning an array rather than the object itself (which is the first item in that array).

Comment: How couldn't I see it ! Thank you man that was the problem ;)